# How to add a string to the end of a PUNICODE_STRING in C

Tags: c, unicode-string

I am trying to modify an existing C mini filter driver but have very limited experience of C. My function recieves two PUNICODE_STRING's both paths to a file on the filesystem.

```
 _In_  PUNICODE_STRING       SourceFile,
 _In_  PUNICODE_STRING       TargetFile,
```

I need to create a new PUNICODE_STRING (called NewTargetFile) then append ".xy" on the end of the NewTargetFile, an not overwite the TargetFile.

I assumed a sensible approch would be to define a new PUNICODE_STRING and copy the TargetFile to the NewTargetFile. Then append the string to the end. But Im clearly way out of my depth here! as I just get a blank value.

```
PUNICODE_STRING NewTargetFile = { 0 };

NewTargetFile = TargetFile;
NT_IF_FAIL_LEAVE(RtlAppendUnicodeToString(NewTargetFile, (PCWSTR)'.ta'));
```

So in a nutshell if my function recieved a TargetFile of "filename.txt" I need to generate a PUNICODE_STRING that has a value "filename.txt.xy"

Comment: `(PCWSTR)'.ta'` is not valid, use `L".ta"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning `NewTargetFile = TargetFile;` you are simply copying the pointer. Every action executed on `NewTargetFile` will be executed on `TargetFile`.

What you need is to create a separate `UNICODE_STRING` for `NewTargetFile` and initialize it using the [`RtlUnicodeStringInit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntstrsafe/nf-ntstrsafe-rtlunicodestringinit) function, then you need to use the [`RtlUnicodeStringCopy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntstrsafe/nf-ntstrsafe-rtlunicodestringcopy) function to copy `TargetFile` into `NewTargetFile`. Finally, you can use the `RtlAppendUnicodeToString()`.

Something like:

```
PUNICODE_STRING NewTargetFile = { 0 };
NTSTRSAFEDDI status; 
// NewTargetFile = TargetFile;
status = RtlUnicodeStringInit(
    NewTargetFile,
    (NTSTRSAFE_PCWSTR) "\0"
);
// check status ...
status = RtlUnicodeStringCopy(
    NewTargetFile,
    TargetFile
);
// check status ...
NT_IF_FAIL_LEAVE(RtlAppendUnicodeToString(NewTargetFile, (PCWSTR)'.ta'));
```

I didn't try the code but that seems to be the problem.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Tony, thats really helped. Now I just need to work out these BSODs but I guess im not allocating enough space or something.

Comment: `PUNICODE_STRING` is just a pointer, you need to *allocate* an actual `UNICODE_STRING` to point at before you can then *initialize* it. Use [`RtlCreateUnicodeString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlcreateunicodestring) for that. Also note, there is an [`RtlUnicodeStringCat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntstrsafe/nf-ntstrsafe-rtlunicodestringcat) function in the same `Ntstrsafe` library as the other `RtlUnicodeString...()` functions you mentioned.